# Change GLDAS Pixel Size in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, resampling

As everyone knows GLDAS data in Google Earth Engine has 25 kilometers spatial resolution. Accordingly I called these data in code editor in order to change the pixel size from 25000m to 250m. I tested many resampling techniques but didn't work. Could anyone guide me please?

code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/0ae03a390790053c17b717f84dc45637

```
Map.centerObject(table);
Map.addLayer(table);


var GLDAS24 = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H")
.filterDate('2020-11-01','2020-11-02')
.filterBounds(table)
.mean().clip(table)
.select('Albedo_inst');

// resampling

var modis = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A1').first())
    .select('EVI');
    
 var modisProjection = modis.projection();
    

var projection = GLDAS24.setDefaultProjection({
  crs: modisProjection,
  scale: 250
})

print(projection)

var GLDAS250 = projection
    .reduceResolution({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      maxPixels: 1024
    })
    .reproject({
      crs: modisProjection
    });

Map.addLayer(GLDAS250,[],'GLDAS250',false)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work" ? Is it that you don't see anything on the map ? Is the size of the pixels that seems the same ? do you get an error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReduceResolution is for aggregating pixels together, and setDefaultProjection only works on things that don't already have a projection (like composites).

You probably want resample(), followed by a reproject().

```
var result = GLDAS24.resample().reproject(modisProjection.atScale(250))
```